# mysql/mysql.h c++ error

Tags: c++, mysql, linux

This is a snippit of my c++ code for mysql insertion.  I found an example of how to do it with mysql.h.  Program runs fine until I add in the following for mysql.  I am new to c++ and have found the same examples in other code, just can't pin point the problem  I have added mysql/mysql.h instead of just mysql.h and also the -i and -l to compiling as suggested through out the web and still no luck.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include    <mysql/mysql.h>


string unknown = "Unknown"

MYSQL *conn;

conn = mysql_init(NULL);
mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "root", "password", "alert", 0, NULL, 0);

mysql_query(conn, "INSERT INTO alert_tbl (alert_srcip, alert_country, alert_destip, alert_desthost, alert_destport, alert_bl) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')", src_ip,country_code,dest_ip,unknown,dest_prt,blip);

mysql_close(conn);
```

g++ test.c -o test -lstdc++ -I/usr/include/mysql -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient

test.c: error: expected , or ; before MYSQL

test.c: error: conn was not declared in this scope

test.c: error: conn was not declared in this scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing semicolon:

```
string unknown = "Unknown";
```

The call to `mysql_query` has too many parameters; it is not a "printf" style function.  You could use sprintf to a separate buffer at the risk of [sql injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  You should use [parameterized queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-prepared-statements.html).

Comment: I feel stupid, thanks.  I feel like the decimal incident on office space.  Thanks.

Comment: mysql_query only takes two parameters.  If you intend to pass the full string like that, you would need to use sprintf first and then pass the resulting string.  However, that leads to the possibility of SQL injection attacks.  You should use a parameterized query.